# awk return preferred matches

Tags: bash, awk

Given this file

```
$ cat foo.txt
0 blah
0 blah
1 blah
2 blah
0 blah
```

I have this command

```
$ awk '/[12]/' foo.txt
1 blah
2 blah
```

However I would only like to search for `1` lines if no `2` lines are found. Desired output for this file would be

```
2 blah
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^2/ {
    found = 1
    print
}
! found && /^1/ {
    matches[++i] = $0
}
END {
    if (! found) {
        for (i in matches) print matches[i]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
/^1/ {
  a[i++] = $0
}
/^2/ {
  b[j++] = $0
}
END {
  if (length(b)) for (p in b) print b[p]
  else for (p in a) print a[p]
}
' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with grep easily enough too:

```
twos=$(grep 2 yourfile)
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then grep 1 yourfile; else echo $twos; fi
```

Comment: shorter `grep 2 yourfile || grep 1 yourfile` however the question is specifially about awk, not grep.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this command, it works for me because I only need the first match of `2` or `1`

```
awk '
/^[12]/ {
  c=$1
  if (c==1 && m) next
  m=$0
  if (c==2 && m) exit
}
END {
  print m
}
' FPAT=. foo.txt
```